# Why is Eugene not punishing the students who are submitting reports so carelessly?

Tags: plot-explanation, pay-it-forward

In **[Pay It Forward](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0223897/)**, why is Eugene not punishing the students who are submitting reports so carelessly?

Here the kid is submitting reports so carelessly, he is not even seeing his teacher, Eugene, in the face.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because HOW he gets the assignment isn't relevant to his function as a educator.

His function is to educate the children in his class in the designated subject matter, test them by handing out homework assignments, receive their completed papers/answers and grade them on their reponses.

Teaching them proper manners and attitudes is considered a **parenting** function and, unfortunately, not something teachers get extra credit for.

Indeed, trying to impose his ideas of proper behaviour could lead to him being censured by his school authorities. He just has to grin and bear the disrespect.